# How do I create a module to run some boilerplate code to keep my codebase DRY

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am doing this in all my vue modules

```
import axios from 'axios'
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFTOKEN'
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

I would like to not repeat this and preferably do something like

```
import axios from './myaxios'
```

I tried:

```
import axios from 'axios'

function myaxios () {
    axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFTOKEN'
    axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
    return axios
}

export default myaxios
```

Does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to call the function. Or just do it outside the function.

```
import axios from 'axios'

function myaxios() {
    axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFTOKEN'
    axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
    return axios
}

export default myaxios()
```

OR

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFTOKEN'
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

export default axios
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing that, you're simply exporting the function `myaxios()` without actually invoking/calling it. You simply have to do it once, and probably in your main `app.js` file (or the first entry point of your app):

In the module, you can export the function as you have done. In your entry file, simply import the module:

```
// Import module
import myaxios from '/path/to/myaxious/module';
```

And then you have to invoke it so that the global settings will be set properly:

```
// Invoke module's default exported function
myaxios();
```